# Can't use program to close an android app

Tags: java, android

I use `ActivityManager` to manage all activity, when activity `onCreate`, I will put this activity to `activityMap` in `ActivityManager`, when activity `onDestroy`, I will remove this activity from `activityMap` in `ActivityManager`.

I use `AlertDialog` to let user close app, when user click want to close app, `ActivityManager` will finish all activity in `activityMap`.

But I can't close my app always, when user click want to close app, I use `Log` to show the activity in `activityMap` is `onDestroy` except an activity, this activity show onPause -> onStart -> onResume -> onStop -> onDestroy, **but it still exist**.

How can I fixed that, thank you!

Here is my `ActivityManager`:

```
public class ActivityManager extends Application{

    public String DF_COVER_ACTIVITY = "CoverActivity";
    public String DF_MAIN_ACTIVITY = "MainActivity";
    public String DF_HOMEPAGE_ACTIVITY = "HomePageActivity";
    public String DF_FULLPOST_ACTIVITY = "FullPostActivity";
    public String DF_REPLYPARENTCOMMENT_ACTIVITY = "ReplyParentCommentActivity";
    public String DF_NEWS_ACTIVITY = "NewsActivity";
    public String DF_FULL_NEWS_ACTIVITY = "FullNewsActivity";
    public String DF_PAY_ACTIVITY = "PayActivity";
    public String DF_PERSON_ACTIVITY = "PersonActivity";
    public String DF_POST_ACTIVITY = "PostActivity";
    public String DF_EDITPROFILE_ACTIVITY = "EditProfileActivity";
    public String DF_BINDING_ACTIVITY = "BindingActivity";
    public String DF_CHANGE_ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY = "ChangeAccountActivity";
    public String DF_GAME_ACTIVITY = "GameActivity";
    public String DF_GAME_WEBVIEW_ACTIVITY = "GameWebviewActivity";

    public String DF_NEW_FRAGMENT = "NewFragment";
    public String DF_HOT_FRAGMENT = "HotFragment";

    private Map<String, Activity> activityMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Fragment> fragmentMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    private static ActivityManager instance;

    private ActivityManager() {}

    public static ActivityManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new ActivityManager();

        return instance;
    }

    public void putActivity(String _activityName, Activity _activity){
        activityMap.put(_activityName, _activity);
    }

    public void putFragment(String _fragmentName, Fragment _fragment){
        fragmentMap.put(_fragmentName, _fragment);
    }

    public Activity getActivity (String _activityName){
        return activityMap.get(_activityName);
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(String _fragmentName){
        return fragmentMap.get(_fragmentName);
    }

    public void removeActivity(String _activityName){
        activityMap.remove(_activityName);
    }

    private void finishActivityMap(){
        for(Object key : activityMap.keySet()){
            if(activityMap.get(key) != null){
                Log.e("ActivityManaqer", String.valueOf(activityMap.get(key)));
                activityMap.get(key).finish();
            }
        }
    }

    public void exit() {
        finishActivityMap();
    }

    public void exitAppAskAlertDialog (final AppCompatActivity _activity) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder (_activity).setMessage ("Exit？").setOnCancelListener (new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel (DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        })
                .setPositiveButton ("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        _activity.finish();
                        exit();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton ("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                }).show ();
    }

}
```

Here is my sample activity, it include **put activity** and **remove activity** to `activityMap` in ActivityManager, **my all activity use these function**: `activtyManager.putActivity()`, `activityManager.removeActivity()`, `activityManager.exitAppAskAlertDialog()`:

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static String TAG = "HomePageActivity";

    private ActivityManager activityManager;
    private NewFragment newFragment;
    private HotFragment hotFragment;

    private postSectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onCreate.");

        initInstance();
        putActivityToActivityManager();
        initItem();
        setViewPager();
        setTab();
        setToolBar();
    }

    private void initInstance(){
        activityManager = ActivityManager.getInstance();
    }

    private void putActivityToActivityManager(){
        activityManager.putActivity(activityManager.DF_HOMEPAGE_ACTIVITY, this);
    }

    private void initItem(){
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.activity_home_page_viewpager);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_home_page_tab);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.activity_home_page_bottom_navigation);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }

    private class postSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public postSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            newFragment = new NewFragment();
            hotFragment = new HotFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return newFragment;

                case 1:
                    return hotFragment;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setViewPager(){
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new postSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    }

    private void setTab(){
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(R.string.New_Tab);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(R.string.Hot_Tab);
    }

    private void setToolBar(){
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    ...
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        activityManager.exitAppAskAlertDialog(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onStart.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onResume.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onPause.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onStop.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "HomePageActivity onDestroy.");
        activityManager.removeActivity(activityManager.DF_HOMEPAGE_ACTIVITY);
    }

}
```

Here is my `Log` when I click want to close app:

```
E/ActivityManaqer: com.gmpsykr.each.HomePageActivity@1fb5f31
E/ActivityManaqer: com.gmpsykr.each.NewsActivity@581c530
E/ActivityManaqer: com.gmpsykr.each.PayActivity@e378096
E/ActivityManaqer: com.gmpsykr.each.PersonActivity@604a240
E/ActivityManaqer: com.gmpsykr.each.GameActivity@b159cd8
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7560ea4010 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x75779fea00, 0x7560ea4000
    endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7560e75600 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x757a9c4de0
D/ViewRootImpl@f86c142[PersonActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=96
E/PersonActivity: PersonActivity onPause.
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1149
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 606127119
E/NewFragment: NewFragment onDestroyView.
E/NewFragment: NewFragment onDestroy.
E/HotFragment: HotFragment onDestroyView.
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1149, ga_screen_class(_sc)=PersonActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-8413159294290485482}]
E/HotFragment: HotFragment onDestroy.
E/HomePageActivity: HomePageActivity onDestroy.
D/ViewRootImpl@c4b229e[HomePageActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=203
E/NewsActivity: NewsActivity onDestroy.
D/ViewRootImpl@dee6b19[NewsActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=185
E/PayActivity: PayActivity onDestroy.
D/ViewRootImpl@78fc107[PayActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=171
E/GameActivity: GameActivity onDestroy.
D/ViewRootImpl@b4e14dd[GameActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=197
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
D/ViewRootImpl@9d7d753[PersonActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
E/PersonActivity: PersonActivity onStart.
D/ViewRootImpl@9d7d753[PersonActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 606127213
E/PersonActivity: PersonActivity onResume.
D/ViewRootImpl@9d7d753[PersonActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2340] new=[0,0][1080,2340] result=0x7 surface={true 504522293248} changed=true
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x75779fea00, 0x7577df4010
D/ViewRootImpl@9d7d753[PersonActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@79a1fe7[PersonActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=PersonActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-8413159294290485482, ga_screen_class(_sc)=PersonActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-8413159294290485487}]
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@79a1fe7[PersonActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.gmpsykr.each ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=96
    Input channel destroyed: fd=181
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x755ef0e010 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x757d985900, 0x755ef0e000
D/ViewRootImpl@ae40a0[PersonActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2340] new=[0,0][1080,2340] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@ae40a0[PersonActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
E/PersonActivity: PersonActivity onStop.
E/PersonActivity: PersonActivity onDestroy.
D/ViewRootImpl@ae40a0[PersonActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=209
D/ProxyCache: Shutdown proxy for HttpUrlSource{url='https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.11483-2/54801417_676291316107173_1984779493574705152_n.mp4?_nc_cat=102&efg=eyJybHIiOjMwNzgsInJsYSI6NTEyLCJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InNkIn0%3D&_nc_oc=AQkIAtzZRaR44MkB8BzFeJCXMFLAm1CCJKLmRr3mVO_LInq_e-f2NBYbAHR1m3_633A&_nc_ht=video.xx&oh=4138b0d82dd446e2d9b1c4d98223dae6&oe=5D8CA57A}
D/ProxyCache: Opened connections: 0
E/HomePageActivity: getUniqueNativeAdCount: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: A simple solution is create an array with only one element and try to access element at index 1 when click "YES" in alert dialog.

Comment: @TaQuangTu it means I need to create an array just save one activity the current activity and when user click yes then I finish the activity it this array?

Comment: I mean you can make your app crash when click "YES" button by an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` by access element that out of array size.

Comment: @TaQuangTu I try your solution, but it will show the app error when the app crash. I want the solution is really close the app, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that you are losing reference to that activity when you replaced it's instance with a new instance. Therefore you can't finish it's lost instance. If that is the case, a quick fix to your problem would be to finish the existing instance before putting a new instance in the map. Lets me show you,

```
public void putActivity(String _activityName, Activity _activity){
        if(activityMap.get(key) != null){
                activityMap.get(key).finish();
            }
        activityMap.put(_activityName, _activity);
    }
```

**Better Solution**
I think storing activities is not a good idea. I would suggest you to read, [Understand Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) to use buit in stack rather than maintaining your own. Also if you want to close an activity and all the underlying activities of the same task having same affinity then you can use, [`finishAffinity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) instead.

Comment: I use your solution and finishAffinity() to close my app, it woks, thank you!